# rsyslog - Turning $RepeatedMsgReduction off completely

Tags: elasticsearch, syslog, rsyslog

Currently, `$RepeatedMsgReduction` is set to `on` in my Docker image. This image acts as a base image for several other Docker images.

What would be the impacts of turning this `off`, especially in a loaded environment? Logs are sent to ElasticSearch so in a loaded environment where there might be high logging, would this turning this off have a significant impact since several Kubernetes use the base image, and therefore would inherit the `$RepeatedMsgReduction` setting?